Asset Collection Samples for TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition
I am writing a term paper for my university on TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition and I need the assets samples for the software and I am unable to find them online. The link on the bottom of the following page (https://archive.topquadrant.com/topbraid-composer-install/) redirects me to the following page (https://www.topquadrant.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Samples-main-7-2.zip) which states that the page does not exist.
Does anyone have the asset collection samples or knows where to find them?
It would be very helpful if anyone has them.
I tried finding them on google but no luck so far and that's why I'm coming here for help.
Thank you!

I would simply ask the Topraid Composer support? They should have the archive somewhere and also could fix the broken link.

I've tried to contact them but I didn't have any luck to get a reply from them.
